# How to convert a list of dictionaries into a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to convert a list of dictionaries into dictionary. I have tried many method but it is showing different errors.

```
def get_list_dict(request):
    data = request.GET.get('dictionary')

    result = dict(item.values() for item in data)
    print(result)

    return JsonResponse({'instance': 'success'})
```

This is the function which is getting `list` `dict` from Ajax function in html and Ajax is sending from html.

And I used `JSON.stringify` before sending it to python function in Ajax function

```
[{"key":"111","value":"222"},{"key":"111","value":"222"}]
```

**What have I tried**

1. I have tried using `reduce` like:

   ```
   res = reduce(lambda aggr, new: aggr.update(new) or aggr, data, {})
   ```

   but it showed:

   ```
   ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
   ```
2. Then I tried extracting separately `key,value` in `for loop` like:

   ```
   newdict={}
   for k,v in [(key,d[key]) for d in data for key in d]:
     if k not in newdict: newdict[k]=[v]
     else: newdict[k].append(v)
   ```

   but it showed:

   ```
   TypeError: string indices must be integers
   ```
3. Then I tried like:

   ```
   pr = dict((key,d[key]) for d in data for key in d)
   ```

   but it showed:

   ```
   TypeError: string indices must be integers
   ```

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to convert this below list dict into dict like

```
{"1111":"2222", "3333":"4444"}
```

I have tried many times but it is still showing errors.

Comment: `{d['key']:d['value'] for d in data}`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, It is showing `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Then your `data` is a string, and not what you showed us.

Comment: @Del Please show exactly what `data` is. Currently the assignment of `data` above cannot be run without generating an error.

Comment: @oda, I have updated the original function that is getting data and converting `list dict` into `dict`.

Comment: Try `json.loads()` to convert string read in to Python list, then apply one of the answers below.

Comment: @oda, It returned `[{'key': '111', 'value': '222'}, {'key': '333', 'value': '444'}]` with only single quotes but it is still in list

Comment: Yes save whatever `json.loads()` returns to a variable, say, `data`, THEN apply one of the answers below to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

data = '[{"key":"111", "value":"222"},{"key":"3333", "value":"4444"}]'
data = json.loads(data)
result = dict(item.values() for item in data)
print(result)
```

output

```
{'111': '222', '3333': '4444'}
```

Note, this assumes python 3.7+ where dicts preserve order of insertion

EDIT TO reflect OP is working with JSON

You need to deserialize first. **BUT I guess whatever framework you use may offer convenience method to do just that for you**. e.g. `requests.Response.json()` method. However you don't show [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and we don't know what you use

Comment: It is showing `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'``

Comment: @Del I do not get an `AttributeError` from running that code.

Comment: But I am getting it

Comment: You copy and pasted the above code and only executed those three statements?

Comment: @Del What is your `old_dict` in your code.

Comment: I took data from your code (and fixed just the misplaced double quote at the end). Given you pass `request` I gues you my be working with JSON string. Please edin your question to include [mre].

Comment: @buran, I have updated the original function that is getting data and converting `list dict` into `dict`.

Comment: What type is `data`? A JSON?

Comment: @buran, Yeah that's why I surprised when before I posted a question about it

Comment: @buran, I used `JSON.stringify` before sending it to python function

Comment: You need to deserialize first, e.g. `data = json.loads(data)` (you need to `import json` first). BUT I guess whatever framework you  use may offer convenience method to do just that for you. e.g. `requests.Response.json()` method. However you don't show [mre] and we don't know what you use.

Comment: Upvoted `buran`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) for converting:
Try this :

```
from collections import ChainMap

data = [{"key":"111","value":"222"},{"key":"3333","value":"4444"}]
data = dict(ChainMap(*data))
print(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this.

```py
old_list = [{"key":"111","value":"222"},{"key":"3333","value":"4444"}]
new_dict = {}

for dict_ in old_list:
    new_dict[dict_['key']]=dict_['value']

print(new_dict)
```

Comment: It is showing `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @Del This code works perfectly also [buran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71900037/convert-list-dict-into-dict/71900059#71900059) code works perfectly. you can use any of these solutions.

Comment: I have updated the original function that is getting data and converting `list dict` into `dict`.